# Get GTK+ theme colors with python and GObject introspection

Tags: python, colors, gtk, introspection, gobject

With introduction of GObject introspection the way to access theme colors through `widget.get_style()` method is gone. I am interested on how to get theme colors when GTK+ is used through GOBject introspection. The solution should preferably work with both versions (2 and 3) but a solution for each of these is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get it from gtk+-2.0, unless your using a pure gtk+-2.0 environment, in which case I think the old GtkStyle methods work.  for example, assuming your not running a Gtk-3.0 environment like gnome-shell

```
import gi
# make sure you use gtk+-2.0
gi.require_version('Gtk', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()

...

style = window.get_style()
print style.lookup_color('fg_color')
```

I think that should still work under a gtk+-2.0 environment.  I don't know for sure as my system is running gnome-shell, and can't easily try this out.

However this method has been deprecated and replaced by GtkStyleContext.  If I use the above code in a gtk+-3.0 environment like gnome-shell it will run, but does not give me the information I'm after.  What I get is

```
(False, <Gdk.Color(red=0, green=0, blue=0)>)
```

---

### EDIT: Looking back at this, I think the above is still giving the correct info. The colour for fg_color is not found, as indicated by the first entry in the tuple result, which is False. Also the window must be visible for the colours to be found.

If I want colour information I want to use the new GtkStyleContext,  for example

```
import gi
# make sure you use gtk+-3.0
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()

...

style_context = window.get_style_context()
print style_context.lookup_color('fg_color')
```

this will give me some real data, which is telling me the 'fg_color' has been found, due to the first entry in the tuple is True.

```
(True, <Gdk.Color(red=0.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=1.000000)>)
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I've been looking for this so hard.

Comment: where can I reference color names (like fg_color)? Apparently there is no bg_color, or fg_color on my system!

Comment: @ThorSummoner I can't really answer your question directly.  The above should work, but if your system doesn't have these colour definitions, it's not going to work.  There was a move to using css to style widgets since gnome-shell.  I've looked for definitions, the closest I have come up with is this https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/8abc6e06b2c551fe60382b45ba413d5f0d49b9ae/gtk/gtkrender.c, but I doubt that'll help you.  Try asking a question